# How can I make notification recieved count for each user

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Whenever admin sends message to a user I want the notification to appear on user dashboard as a counter on the menu, below is the code i have tried in my header menu

```
<li class="nav-item">
@foreach($Notif as $notification)
<a href="{{ url('dashboard/notification') }}">Notification <span>    
{{ $notification->count() }}
</span></a>
@endforeach
</li>
```

[Image of where notification is on header (user header)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouN4O.png)

[Image of admin panel to send message to user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25rA8.png)

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications#database-notifications Its help you

Comment: This is the one i just tried... also didn't give any error and no result

Comment: <li class="nav-item">
         <a href="{{ url('dashboard/notification') }}">Notification <span>
             
           $user = App\User::find(1);

                                        foreach ($user->notifications as $notification) {
                                        echo $notification->type;
                                        }
         </span></a>
         
         <!--<a href="{{ url('dashboard/profile') }}">Profile</a>-->
        
        </li>

Comment: If you want reach count use `{{ $Notif->count() }}` instead of `$notifaction->count()`

Comment: No different either

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what is `$Notif`?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am using this way to get unreadnotification counter

```
Auth::user()->unreadNotifications->count() ;
Auth::user()->readNotifications->count() ;
```

does this what you need ?